# Etymology of 引き分け: same as English?

Tags: etymology

The verb 引く gives 引き出し ('drawer'), which is a straightforward etymology shared by Japanese and English (and French and probably more). But 引き分け seems to also have an etymology similar to 'draw' (as 'tie' in sports) in English; and this etymology is not so self-evident. Is there a shared logic, is it a coincidence, was the word imported and translated?

Answer (score 4):

- 引き出し is 引き "pulling" + 出し "coming out".  By extension, "that which pulls and comes out" or "that which is pulled and comes out": a drawer.

  - Technically speaking, the Japanese term does not share its etymology with any other known word in another language: etymology refers to the specific derivation of a word and its constituent parts.  Neither English nor French have any words even remotely related to 引き出し (aside from any borrowings from Japanese).  The word-formation process in the three languages might be vaguely analogous, which I think is what you mean.
- 引き分け is 引き "pulling" + 分け "splitting, dividing".  By extension, "that which pulls and divides", or "that which is pulled and divided".

  - In the absence of any specific number, this often refers to splitting something in two halves, and that sense in the context of a competition yields the idea of the two teams being equally matched: a tie, with neither winning and neither losing.

Comment: As an addition, 分ける doesn't only mean "divide" but "divide into quotas" and even suggests "distribute" or "share".